# infinality fonts and Windows fonts emulation

Tags: linux, fonts

I want to emulate Windows 7 fonts on my Ubuntu 13.10 system. I installed [infinality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html) and tried a couple of themes via  `infctl.sh` (`Win7` and `OSX2` ones). Alas, none of them was fully suitable: `OSX2` theme needs to be darker and `Win7` theme needs to be thicker.

In tried to modify the filter matrix via `infinality-settings.sh`. It writes the proper (modified) values to the environment variables, but nothing happens  to my rendered fonts. I restarted my machine several times, but it does not help.

Cannot you tell me the proper way to modify my filter settings?

P.S. My antialiasing settings are [here.](http://i.zlowiki.ru/140318_a2bb873d.png)

P.P.S. My printenv dumps are [here.](http://pastebin.com/fmWnjRhK)

[image: A comparison between real Windows fonts and pre-defined themes of <code>infinality</code>]

Comment: I don't think that the command-line options mean too much here. I can change themes via infctl.sh, and the font themes are changed. I test it by running gedit from time to time. But when I use infinality-settings.sh, the variables are written but it changes nothing.

Comment: yes, I read your initial description. So sorry that didn't help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, the reason was rather simple: I had my `FreeType` installed not from [no1wantdthisname PPA](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ppa), but from the default Ubuntu repository. So, the Freetype itself was not patched, only fontconfig-infinality was installed.

Comment: You can (should) accept your own answer, click on the pipe icon on the left side.